# Getting 405 Error Method is not Allowed in Online Server (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, post, get, cpanel

It works fine on my local server and computer when I upload it to the online server and whenever I try to update a field like description or sometimes when inserting I get 405 and says that method is not allowed.
I used same method (POST) as in web.php and also in my view.

```
                        <form action="/updateannouncement" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            @csrf
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $announce->id }}">

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-form-label" for="title"><i class="fa fa-pen"></i> Announcement
                                            Title</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" value="{{ $announce->title }}" id="title"
                                            placeholder="Enter ..." required>
                                    </div>
```

this is web.php

```
Route::post('/insertannouncement', 'announcementController@insert');
Route::post('/updateannouncement', 'announcementController@update')->middleware('restrict');
```

**I realy want help on this guys!!!**

Comment: what is this `restrict` middleware doing?

Comment: it's for user restrictions

Comment: show the code of what it is doing

Comment: here bro if ($request->user()->role !='admin') {
            return response()->view('restricted');
        }

        return $next($request);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved!

The Problem was in the **CPanel** in **MODSecrity** which I have to turn it off for my domain when done that error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

run following command :

```
php artisan route:clear
```

or

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

if it didn't work, take a look on your middleware

Comment: I have tried this many times and it didn't worked as well

Answer (score -1):

Instead of adding a route name like `/updateannouncement` use the route name in the form. see in the [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#named-routes)

In your case, it should be like this...

```php
Route::post('/insertannouncement', 'announcementController@insert')->name('announcement.store');
Route::post('/updateannouncement', 'announcementController@update')->middleware('restrict')->name('announcement.update');
```

and use in the form

```php
<form action="{{ route('announcement.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   @csrf
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $announce->id }}">

   <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-form-label" for="title"><i class="fa fa-pen"></i> Announcement
           Title</label>
       <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" value="{{ $announce->title }}" id="title"
           placeholder="Enter ..." required>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @AnasHassan please check in the ```php artisan route:list``` to verify your route

Comment: it has the route I want which is POST and all other routes also

Comment: please check the solution which I posted. there is a difference between adding ```/updateannouncement``` and ```route('announcement.store')```